# Adding PatchCollection with Affine Transformations

Tags: python, matplotlib, affinetransform

I have some `patches` on which I apply different `Affine2D` transformations in `matplotlib`.
Is there a possibility to add them as a `collections.PatchCollection`? Somehow I am only able to draw them if I call `ax.add_patch()` separately for each of them.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt, patches, collections, transforms

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

trafo1 = transforms.Affine2D().translate(+0.3, -0.3).rotate_deg_around(0, 0, 45) + ax.transData
trafo2 = transforms.Affine2D().translate(+0.3, -0.3).rotate_deg_around(0, 0, 65) + ax.transData

rec1 = patches.Rectangle(xy=(0.1, 0.1), width=0.2, height=0.3, transform=trafo1, color='blue')
rec2 = patches.Rectangle(xy=(0.2, 0.2), width=0.3, height=0.2, transform=trafo2, color='green')

ax.add_collection(collections.PatchCollection([rec1, rec2], color='red', zorder=10))

# ax.add_patch(rec1)
# ax.add_patch(rec2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `PatchCollection` does not support individually transformed elements. From the [Matplotlib documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/collections_api.html), we can read a `Collection` is a

> class for the efficient drawing of large collections of objects that share most properties, e.g., a large number of line segments or polygons.

You can understand this with creating the collection without any individually transformed patches:

```py
rec1 = patches.Rectangle(xy=(0.1, 0.1), width=0.2, height=0.3, color='blue')
rec2 = patches.Rectangle(xy=(0.2, 0.2), width=0.3, height=0.2, color='green')
col = collections.PatchCollection([rec1, rec2], color='red', zorder=10)
print(col.get_transform())
```

That prints `IdentityTransform()` for the last statement, and correctly displays the (non-transformed) patches. These patches can be transformed all-at-once from the `PatchCollection`, without individual specification.

On the contrary, when you apply the individual transform for each patch (like in your case), the `.get_transform()` method returns an empty list. This is probably due to the fact that `PatchCollection` classes are made to gather `patches` with a lot of common attributes in order to accelerate the drawing efficiency (as mentioned above), including the `transform` attribute.

**Note**: on [this answer](http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/How-to-draw-a-collection-of-oriented-triangles-tp47632p47635.html), you can find a workaround with a `patch` to `path` conversion, then to a `PathCollection` with an increase drawing efficiency compared to individual patch draw.